# How to open another excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to write a script to open another excel.

My code

```
Sub test()
filetoopen=thisworkbook.worksheet("sheet1").Range("D18")
```

Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Sub test()
filetoopen = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D18")
Workbooks.Open FileName:=filetoopen
ActiveWindow.ActivatePrevious
```